# How can I specify address in facebook place search

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If I want to find places near some address in facebook graph search search, given than I know it's street, zip, what is the syntax for the query to graph api?

If I call `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/search?type=place` I get following error:

`(#100) Must specify location or address or search query for place search`

I know, that it is possible to specify location in a form of latitude/longitude, but with lat/lon it does not return all places (maybe because some of them do not have lat/lon specified in location).

The error says 'location *or address*'. What is the syntax for specifying address in a form of street/zip? Is that possible at all?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search does not mention searching by address at all. My guess would be that the error message is just wrong in that regard; but you can of course file a bug report and ask them about it if you like. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify a query string for search using `q=your_search_query`

Search query needs to be a string

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/search?type=place&q=bangalore&access_token=your_token works for me

You can specify lat/lng using center parameter

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/search?center=37.76,-122.427&q=coffee&type=place&access_token=your_token

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.7#search